# why a generic struct parameterized by blittable type is not an unmanaged type?

Tags: .net, f#, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have one function foo, which takes an unmanaged type, then I create a generic struct, which require the type parameter to be unmanaged:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vector4<'T when 'T:unmanaged> =
    val x : 'T
    val y : 'T
    val z : 'T
    val w : 'T
    new (x, y, z, w) = { x = x; y = y; z = z; w = w }

let foo<'T when 'T:unmanaged> (o:'T) =
    printfn "%A" o
    printfn "%d" sizeof<'T>

let bar() =
    let o = Vector4<float32>(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f)
    foo o  // here has error
```

but I got compiling error:

```
Error 4 A generic construct requires that the type 'Vector4<float32>' is an unmanaged type
```

I checked the MSDN, it syas:

> The provided type must be an unmanaged type. Unmanaged types are
>   either certain primitive types (sbyte, byte, char, nativeint,
>   unativeint, float32, float, int16, uint16, int32, uint32, int64,
>   uint64, or decimal), enumeration types, nativeptr<_>, or a non-generic
>   structure whose fields are all unmanaged types.

Why a generic struct which requires blittable type parameter is not an unmanaged type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types are not supported by Interop: [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229590.aspx), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1579559/55209)

> The COM model does not support the concept of generic types.
>   Consequently, generic types cannot be used directly for COM interop.

Type alias is no help in this case unfortunately:

```
[<Struct>]
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type Vector4<'T when 'T:unmanaged> =
    val x : 'T
    val y : 'T
    val z : 'T
    val w : 'T
    new (x, y, z, w) = { x = x; y = y; z = z; w = w }

type Vector4float = Vector4<float32>

let inline foo<'T when 'T:unmanaged> (o:'T) =
    printfn "%A" o
    printfn "%d" sizeof<'T>

let bar() =
    let o = new Vector4float(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f)
    foo o //  A generic construct requires that the type 'Vector4float' is an unmanaged type
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, I'm not doing COM interop, but with C function PInvoke. What I need is a blittable type, which has the same layout in memory. Is this also impossible?

Comment: “which has the same layout in memory” — how could you guarantee it with generic type? `Vector4<Int64>` and `Vector4<Int32>` will have different layout, that's the point.

Comment: I mean, has the same layout in .NET and in C, because C code will process it. So, my question is, if I remove the constraint of unmanaged, then I can pin that object, then get the pinned pointer, and can I send that pointer to C?

Comment: for example, my C function has signature void foo(vector4float* d); and then I create a Vector4<float32> in .net, pin it and send the pointer to C. does this work?