# How to use Marshal.PtrToStructure to copy a generic struct?

Tags: c#, generics, marshalling

How can I do a blittable copy from bytes in memory onto a generic struct in C#? Trying to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` throws `ArgumentException: The specified Type must not be a generic type`.

Here's a scenario; I'm trying to read the EXE/DLL file format [PE32/PE32+ Windows-Specific Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN#optional-header-windows-specific-fields-image-only) from a .NET assembly. The field types are different between 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies: some are always 2 or 4 bytes, but a few fields are the native word size.

If I define a generic struct with the appropriate fields, I find that [generic types are not supported by interop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676438/771768):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<Tint>
{
  public Tint ImageBase;
  public uint SectionAlignment;
  public uint FileAlignment;
  public ushort OSMajor;
  public ushort OSMinor;
  public ushort UserMajor;
  public ushort UserMinor;
  public ushort SubSysMajor;
  public ushort SubSysMinor;
  public uint Reserved;
  public uint ImageSize;
  public uint HeaderSize;
  public uint FileChecksum;
  public ushort SubSystem;
  public ushort DLLFlags;
  public Tint StackReserveSize;
  public Tint StackCommitSize;
  public Tint HeapReserveSize;
  public Tint HeapCommitSize;
  public uint LoaderFlags;
  public uint NumberOfDataDirectories;
}

static class Program
{
  const ushort MAGIC_PE32 = 0x10b;
  const ushort MAGIC_PE32_PLUS = 0x20b;


  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var dll = args.SingleOrDefault() ?? typeof(Program).Assembly.Location;
    Console.WriteLine(dll);

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dll);
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64();

    // Ignore ugly hardcoded pointer math
    var peHeaderMagic = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ushort>((IntPtr)(ptr + 0x98));

    object peHeader;
    switch (peHeaderMagic)
    {
      case MAGIC_PE32:
        Console.WriteLine("PE32");
        peHeader = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<uint>>((IntPtr)(ptr + 0xB4));
        break;
      case MAGIC_PE32_PLUS:
        Console.WriteLine("PE32+");
        peHeader = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<ulong>>((IntPtr)(ptr + 0xB0));
        break;
      default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown PE magic");
    }

    // do something with the header
    foreach (var field in peHeader.GetType().GetFields())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0,24} = 0x{1:X}", field.Name, field.GetValue(peHeader));
    }
  }
```

throws

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The specified Type must not be a generic type. (Parameter 'structureType')
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure[T](IntPtr ptr)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in folder/Program.cs:line 53
```

How can I get `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` or some other API to read my data?

---

One thing I tried is using `unmanaged` constraint which in C# 8 makes the struct an [constructed unmanaged type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types), but that didn't change the exception:

```cs
struct PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<Tint> where Tint : unmanaged
```

---

An obvious workaround is to just copy-paste the entire struct into different separate definitions but that doesn't answer the question. Ideally, I'd like the answer to work without needing `unsafe`.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to make non-generic structs with a generic field (which with some handwaving seems like a C++ subclass or template instantiation):

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
sealed class PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields32
{
  public PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<uint> val;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
sealed class PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields64
{
  public PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields<ulong> val;
}
```

Then use them as a temporary for coping:

```cs
      case MAGIC_PE32:
        Console.WriteLine("PE32");
        var tmp32 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields32>((IntPtr)(ptr + 0xB4));
        peHeader = tmp32.val;
        break;
      case MAGIC_PE32_PLUS:
        Console.WriteLine("PE32+");
        var tmp64 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PEHeaderWindowsNtSpecificFields64>((IntPtr)(ptr + 0xB0));
        peHeader = tmp64.val;
        break;
```