# call C++ function which is having std::list as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, clr, marshalling

here i am writing wrapper to call c++ function in c# project.Here i am not using Dllimport method. I am looking C++/CLR approach. using C++/CLR approach we can add Dll directly to the c# project.

In my C++/CLR i have one function like below.

`int StartScan(std::list<SomeObject*> *DeviceList);`

i want call this function from C#. what's the equivalent property to call from C#. 
i have tried with LinkedList which is equivalent property for **std::list**, if we used P/Invoke Approach.

Comment: A `std::list` is implementation-defined in C++.  It is implemented differently for different compilers and compiler versions.  There is no way C# is going to match it with a PInvoke.  Even different C++ compilers and versions can't match each other's `std::list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list in C# using P/Invoke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529316/how-to-return-a-list-in-c-sharp-using-p-invoke)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579559/marshalling-net-generic-types

Comment: c++/CLI doesn't magically allow all c/c++ types to be accessible from c#.  Rather you are meant to create new or modify existing c++ types to be CLR-aware.

Comment: You want the STL-CLR library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/stl-clr-library-reference You can link it to .NET code with collection adapters or the IEnumerable and ICollection interfaces.  In particular: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/list-stl-clr

Comment: @Davislor Quite interesting library... Not sure if it is useful in this case... I think he should simply expose a `System::Collections::::Generics::List<xxx>` in the C++/clr

Comment: Thanks for you answers. It helps me a lot. now i have list. like below System::Collections::Generic::List<MyStruct>^ tmp =gcnew List<MyStruct>(); but its giving error as not a valid generic argument. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Generic type arguments must be either reference types or value types.  If `MyStruct` is POD, declare it a `value struct`. That’s the simplest fix. You could instead make it a `ref class` that implements `IEquatable` and `iComparable`, but that would be more complicated. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c570k3f3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Since your question implies that you are using C++/CLR and that you have control over that code, you should write the public method C# is supposed to use to take a managed `List<T>` object as the parameter, and then copy the contents to the `std::list<SomeObject*>` object that your C++ code apparently actually needs.

You'll need a managed type for `T`, something that is equivalent to the `SomeObject` you're using in C++. You'll have to clone those objects from the managed type to your `std:list` as well.

If you aren't able to change the C++/CLI code, then you'd have to write a shim DLL to handle the conversion. P/invoke doesn't know how to do this automatically.

If you are able to use the STL/CLR library, as recommended in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710507/call-c-function-which-is-having-stdlist-as-parameter/42711159#comment72543322_42710507), i.e. you can switch your `std::` library usages to the `cliext::` library, then it includes code to help with this. For example, you can create a `cliext::list` object, pass your managed `List<T>` to its constructor, and it will copy the contents of your managed list to the `cliext::list` object.

For example: [How to: Convert from a .NET Collection to a STL/CLR Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546599.aspx)