# How to use C++ DLL that returns vector

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ DLL that I'm trying to use in a C# application. The C++ DLL returns an object containing several vector types. C# throws a `Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.`

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct InputDLL
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
    public int e;
};


[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct OutputDLL
{
    public List<int> vectorout;
};


public class TestVectorDLL
{
    [DllImport( "TestVectorDLL.dll",
        EntryPoint = "?RunDLL@@YA?AUOutputDLL@@UInputDLL@@@Z",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
    public static extern OutputDLL RunDLL( InputDLL input );
}
```

There was a DLL written for the sole purpose of me testing a return type containing a vector. The DLL takes the 5 integer values as input and returns those 5 integers in a vector data type. My code to use the DLL is:

```
InputDLL input = new InputDLL()
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = 5
};

OutputDLL output = TestVectorDLL.RunDLL(input);
```

The above line throws a `Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.`

Can someone point me on how to read the C++ return correctly?

Here is the testing C++ DLL's .h include:

```
#pragma once  

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
#define  EPS_API __declspec(dllexport) 

struct InputDLL
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
};

struct OutputDLL
{
    vector<int> vectorout;
};

EPS_API OutputDLL RunDLL(InputDLL Input);
```

Comment: Post the C++ signature.

Comment: @Aybe I edited my question to include the .h - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Marshalling C++ classes is a major pain in the butt. You might try following this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16003004/2819245. But probably the better option is to either design your DLL exports without using C++ types or perhaps write an additional mixed assembly in C++/CLI (in which you could easily and more or less directly translate your vector into whatever .NET types you need)

Comment: Got me by a few seconds, that's what I was going to suggest !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a list in C# using P/Invoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529316/how-to-return-a-list-in-c-sharp-using-p-invoke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing arguments between managed and native methods, you should stick to the available marshalling types or implement your own custom marshaller. AFIK. there is no standard marshaller for std:vector. You have two options: 1. A more humble implementation using available marshalling types (see the code below). 2. Implement ICustomMarshaller interface for std:vector. You will find a description of this interface here: 
[ICustomMarshaller interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
// A more modest marshalling example:
// C# code


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct input_struct
        {
            public int a;
            public int b;
            public int c;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct output_struct
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public int[] o;
        }

        public class NativeVector
        {
            [DllImport("NativeVector.dll")]
            public static extern int RunDll(input_struct i, ref output_struct o);
        }

        class Program
        {
           static output_struct output = new output_struct();

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                input_struct input;
                input.a = 1;
                input.b = 2;
                input.c = 3;
                output.o = new int[3];
                NativeVector.RunDll(input, ref output);
            }
        }
    }


    // C++ code

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <vector>

    struct input
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };

    struct output
    {
        int v[3];
    };

    extern "C" 
    {
        __declspec(dllexport) int _stdcall  RunDll(struct input i, struct output& o)
        {
            o.v[0] = i.a;
            o.v[1] = i.b;
            o.v[2] = i.c;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The 'more humble' approach can be adapted for what we're needing. Thank you Victor.